# Python listas melhor aluno

Tags: python

supondo que tenho x alunos que tiveram x notas. como ponho o nome do aluno que teve a melhor nota?

```
# coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
import math
nAlunos=0
while True:
    nAlunos=eval(input('Indique o número de alunos:'))
    if 1<=nAlunos<=100:
        break
    else:
        print('O número de alunos tem de ser entre 1 e 100')
        print()
ListaNomes=[0 for i in range(0,nAlunos)]
ListaNotas=[0 for i in range(0,nAlunos)]
reprovados=0
suficiente=0
bom=0
muitobom=0
for i in range(0,nAlunos):
    ListaNomes[i]=input('Nome:')
    while True:
        ListaNotas[i]=eval(input('Nota:'))
        if 0<=ListaNotas[i]<=20:
            if 0<=ListaNotas[i]<10:
                reprovados=reprovados+1
            elif 10<=ListaNotas[i]<14:
                suficiente=suficiente+1
            elif 14<=ListaNotas[i]<17:
                bom=bom+1
            elif 17<=ListaNotas[i]<20:
                muitobom=muitobom+1
            break
        else:
            print('A nota tem de estar entre 0 e 20')
            print() 
PercentagemReprovados=(reprovados*100)/len(ListaNotas)
PercentagemSuficiente=(suficiente*100)/len(ListaNotas)
PercentagemBom=(bom*100)/len(ListaNotas)
PercentagemMuitobom=(muitobom*100)/len(ListaNotas)
print()
for i in range(0,nAlunos):
    print(ListaNomes[i])
    print(ListaNotas[i])
print()
print(PercentagemReprovados)
print()
print(PercentagemSuficiente)
print(PercentagemBom)
print(PercentagemMuitobom)
print()
print(max(ListaNotas))
for i in max(ListaNotas[i]):
    print(ListaNomes[i])
```

a ultima linha está a dar me erro e não estou a perceber como devo adicionar o nome do aluno que teve a nota mais alta

Answer (score -1, accepted):

você precisa saber a posição da lista de notas que tem a melhor nota e imprimir o nome do aluno na mesma posição. Basta adicionar duas linhas:

```
argmax = max(enumerate(ListaNotas), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
print(ListaNomes[argmax])
```

existem outras maneiras de fazer isso. Se você quiser pegar todos os alunos que tiraram a melhor nota pode fazer:

```
melhor_nota=max(ListaNotas)
melhores = [ListaNomes[i] for i in range(len(ListaNotas)) if ListaNotas[i] == melhor_nota]
```

Comment: Se tivessem dois alunos a mesma nota deveriam de aparecer os dois que tiveram a melhor nota, não sei se é possível aparecerem todos os alunos que tiveram a melhor mas se me conseguir ajudar agradeço

Comment: Eu adicionei o que fazer para ter todos os alunos com a melhor nota

Comment: dá para aparecer o resultado sem aparecer entre [ ]? por exemplo agora aparece ['Tiago','Ruben'] ... dá para aparecer só Tiago , Ruben   ?

Comment: dá sim, você pode fazer `print(str(melhores)[1:-1])` ou `print(", ".join(melhores))`. No primeiro os nomes aparecem entre aspas e no segundo não